# fwrite doesnt print anything to stdout

Tags: c, stdout, fwrite

When I run this small code and enter 3 integers on the console, it doesn't print out as it should due to the fwrite statement. It prints only after I keep hitting enter for some time. Help?
P.S: Learning faster ways than scanf and printf.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int size[3];
    fread(&size,sizeof(int),3,stdin);
    fwrite(&size,sizeof(int),3,stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `fread` reads binary data, not formatted text, so when you tell it to read 3 "ints" it will read 3*4=12 bytes of raw data from stdin.  If you type "1" "2" "3" that's only three bytes of text, plus three newlines.  Once you type twelve bytes it will probably get past that part, but then your program is probably broken, assuming you wanted to read and write actual text.

You mean you're "learning faster ways than scanf and printf."  Well, this is not a faster way, it's just a broken way.  If you're having a performance issue in some code using scanf & printf, please ask a separate question and we can help with that.

Comment: You can input 012345678912 then the result is what you expect, as the size of "0" is 1 byte.See doc for *fread*: The  function  fread() reads nmemb elements of data, each size bytes long, from the
       stream pointed to by stream, storing them at the location given by ptr.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot John! Well, actually i had to scan a large no. of 'ints' from stdin, sort them and finally print them on stdout. Using the conventional 'scanf' and 'printf' method takes a LOT of time. What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Size of `int` is 4 bytes so your `fread()` will try to read 12 bytes (4 * 3).

When you enter something like this on console

```
1 2 3
```

it is 6 chars = 3 numbers + 2 spaces + 1 \n

Hence you would have to press enter at lease 6 times so that it reads 6 more bytes.

Better to use `scanf()` to get integers as

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &size[0], &size[1], &size[2]);
```